# How to supply custom init script to Azure instance

Tags: linux, scripting, azure, init

Is it possible to create an instance specific init script and pass it to a virtual machine that is created via the API of Microsoft Azure? I know this from AWS, but could not find a way to do this on MS Azure.

The only workaround I can think of it to create a generic script for my own image that then somehow downloads a custom script based on the hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the answer to this on StackOverflow ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19906341/272109)). Reposting here (with a few tweaks) as well, for completeness...

Take a look at the [REST API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157194.aspx)  for creating a Virtual Machine deployment, specifically the `<CustomData>` element. This lets you inject up to 64K of binary data to your VM during provisioning, which results in a `CustomData.bin` file being generated inside your VM. This should help you with first-time init, and works with both Linux and Windows Virtual Machines.

Note that this isn't yet implemented in the command-line tools - you'll need to call the API directly. There's now a [pull request](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat/pull/1048) posted implementing the proper CLI wrapper code for `CustomData` but it hasn't yet been accepted.

Comment: Thanks, not as easy as hoped, but definitely something to work on.

Comment: Hopefully it will be easier once the CLI is updated. If you look at the [proposed change](https://github.com/szarkos/azure-sdk-tools-xplat/commit/8f5ec9c649ea5570d5345010ff78748721a8e489) to the CLI, there will be a new parameter to `azure vm create` (`-d` or `--custom-data`) that takes a filename, which gets encoded automagically for you.